# Access JSON index as PHP variable

Tags: php, json

$json:

```
{
   "https://google.com/": {
      "share": {
         "comments": 10,
         "shares": 20
      },
      "id": "https://google.com/"
   }
}
```

PHP from error below:

```
$url = "https://google.com/";
... json is fetched here and set as $json
$count = $json->$url->comments;
```

Error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$comments in /mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme/functions.php on line 797

My partial fix:

```
$count = $json->$url->share->comments;
```

Comment: `var_dump($json);` outputs what?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/sa7N1 Works fine.

Comment: I don't understand. You're trying to access `comments`, but that's inside `share`, so you need it first in the chain. Your 'partial fix' is not partial at all, as noted by @u_mulder...

Comment: @FirstOne because that's how the theme was wrote - I didn't write the existing code.

Comment: I didn't question the structure, but your attempt to read it. Besides, checking your edit, it was already correct, apparently. It looks like it's working now, so let's move on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap the `$url` in curly braces:

```
$count = $json->{$url}->share->comments;
```

Comment: If this was the problem, then wouldn't the notice reference `share` instead of `comments`?

Comment: @bassxzero Correct. I edited the question to answer that. I did a partial fix but marked it as the current code with the error.

Answer (score -1):

Try decode the json first.

```
$json = json_decode($json);

$url = "https://google.com/";

$count = $json->$url->share->comments;
```

Comment: It's already decoded or else the notice would say something about `trying to access method or member of string`